# Prove that for all m ∈ ω and all n ∈ ω, if m ∈ n, then n ⊄ m.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Omega is the set of all natural numbers so I don't get what it means when it says m ∈ n and how to show n is not a subset of m. 
I was guessing you'd use proof by contradiction but I'm not sure.

Comment: If $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers, not sets. It would then be incorrect to state $m \in n$. Did you type in the question correctly?

Comment: @lyeeke Not under the interpretation of natural numbers as ordinals, which is clearly what OP means by using the notation $\omega$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: OP, do you know the definition of ordinal numbers?

Comment: Yes this is how it was given to my in my textbook. There is a definition that says "we will identify omega as the set that satisfies x ∈ ω if and only if  x is in every inductive set," not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: @AbigailWebb My bad. I think that should be included in the question for context.

Answer (score 1):

In this context we define each number as the set of all numbers which are less than the number we are defining, so any number is a set (Actually, anything is a set in set theory, that's the main point.). So for example we have

$0 = \{ \}$

$1 = \{ 0 \}$

$2 = \{ 0, 1 \}$

$3 = \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$

etc.

Actually, if we want to have formal and precise definition for numbers, we have the following:

$\omega$ is the smallest set like $X$ with the following properties.

- $\emptyset \in X$
- $n\in X \to n \cup \{ n \} \in X$

The first sentence says zero is in $X$, and the second one says if $n$ is in $X$, then $n+1$ is in $X$. We call $n+1$ which is formally $n \cup \{ n \}$, the successor of $n$ and denote it by $n^+$.

With this point of view it make sense to assert that $m\in n$, intuitively it means $m < n$, but we do not have the *less-than* relation and it's properties, we just make the numbers inductively and now we need to prove a fact about the structures we made, numbers.

Here we need a formal proof not just some intuitive thoughts, since the assertion is trivial, but we need to prove it formally i.e. using definitions.

By the hypothesis $m\in n$, we can prove that $m \subset n$. We can use induction on $n$.

- $n=0$, in this case, there is no $m$ s. t. $m\in n$, since $n = \{ \}$.
- $n = n'^+ = n' \cup \{ n' \}$, in this case we have two possibilities, either $m \in n'$ or $m \in \{ n' \}$. If $m \in n'$ then by induction hypothesis $m \subset n'$ and therefor $m \subset n$. If $m \in \{ n' \}$ then $m = n'$ and we know that $n' \subset n$ (since $n= n' \cup \{ n' \}$), so $m \subset n$.

Now as you said we can complete the proof by contradiction, let $n \subset m$, and we proved $m \subset n$. But this is not possible. (Note we have $\subset$ relation not $\subseteq$ relation.)

Comment: It is supposed to be prove n is not a subset of m, not just ⊂ .

Comment: we proved that $m\subset n$ so they're not equal, therefore we can easily say that neither $n\subset m$ nor $n=m$.